# Pandas match data from one column in a df to data in another df

Tags: python, pandas

This feels like such a simple thing yet I'm having the hardest time figuring it out.

Pretty much I have two data frames. One containing all college basketball games and another containing every teams stats.

I need to create two new columns in my game data frame called 'Away Team SRS' and 'Home Team SRS'. I want to use the column 'Away Team' in the game data and match that to the team in the team data and then take that SRS score and add it to the 'Away Team SRS' and same for home.

Below you can see how my dfs are set up. I tried using `df.at`, `df.loc`, among other things and nothing seems to work. I imagine there has to be an easy way to do this since you can do it in 20 seconds on excel with XLOOKUP.

| Away Team | Home Team | Away Team Score | Home Team Score | Away Team SRS | Home Team SRS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boston College | Duke | 100 | 2 | To be filled | To be filled |

| Team | SRS | Other Stats... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boston College | 0 | stuff |
| Duke | 0 | stuff |

EDIT: I found a solution:

```
main_data['Away Team SRS'] = main_data['Away Team'].map(team_data.set_index('School')['SRS'])
main_data['Home Team SRS'] = main_data['Home Team'].map(team_data.set_index('School')['SRS'])
```

Thank you anyway!!

Comment: Did you read the section titled “How to combine data from multiple tables” in the Getting Started chapter of the pandas documentation?

Comment: If you found a solution you should post it in the Answer section below, not in the question.